# Views are not displayed in the ViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple ViewPager backed with a PagerAdapter, but for the views i instantiate never display in the view pager.

I have a requirement to develop the UI purely in code.  So i can't inflate an xml layout in the instantiateItem method.  Unfortunately almost all the examples i've seen are inflating xml, which obviously doesn't work.

So i have an PagerAdapter, (i do NOT want to use fragments) with a ViewPager as below.  The adapter takes some data

```
val viewAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(data)
viewPager.adapter = viewAdapter
```

ViewPagerAdapter looks like this:

```
inner class ViewPagerAdapter(val data: List<Item>) : PagerAdapter() {
    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View?, obj: Any?): Boolean {
        return obj == view
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return data.count()
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup?, position: Int): Any {
        val rootLayout = LinearLayout(container?.context)
        rootLayout.layoutParams = rootLayout.setDimensions(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        rootLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL

        val title = Button(container?.context)
        title.text = "Title"
        title.textSize = 13f
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        rootLayout.addView(title)

        val subtitle = Button(container?.context)
        subtitle.text = "Subtitle"
        subtitle.textSize = 13f
        subtitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        rootLayout.addView(subtitle)

        (container as ViewPager).addView(rootLayout)
        return rootLayout
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return data[position].title
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup?, position: Int, obj: Any?) {
        if (obj == null) return
           container?.removeView(obj as View?)
        }
    }
}
```

For the life of me i can't see what's wrong with this code.  I've tried changing the layouts, textview to a button but nothing works.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Update:

I've created a simple app to prove that i'm not doing anything silly.  Should be able to copy and paste this and run it, provided you've added the relevant libs.

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val rootLayout = CoordinatorLayout(this)
    rootLayout.layoutParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

    val appBarLayout = AppBarLayout(this)
    rootLayout.addView(appBarLayout)
    appBarLayout.layoutParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    val tabLayout = TabLayout(this)

    tabLayout.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_FIXED
    tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL
    appBarLayout.addView(tabLayout)
    tabLayout.layoutParams = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    //add viewpager
    val viewPager = ViewPager(this)
    viewPager.id = 11122

    val viewAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter()
    viewPager.adapter = viewAdapter

    rootLayout.addView(viewPager)
    viewPager.layoutParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
    setContentView(rootLayout)
}


inner class ViewPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter() {

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View?, obj: Any?): Boolean {
        return obj == view
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup?, position: Int): Any {
        val rootLayout = LinearLayout(container?.context)
        rootLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        rootLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL

        val title = Button(container?.context)
        title.text = "Title"
        title.textSize = 13f
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        rootLayout.addView(title)

        val subtitle = Button(container?.context)
        subtitle.text = "Subtitle"
        subtitle.textSize = 13f
        subtitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        rootLayout.addView(subtitle)

        val viewPager = container as ViewPager
        viewPager.addView(rootLayout, 0)
        return rootLayout
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return "Title: $position"
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup?, position: Int, obj: Any?) {
        if (obj == null) return
        when (obj) {
            is ArrayList<*> -> for (item in obj) {
                container?.removeView(item as View?)
            }
            else -> container?.removeView(obj as View?)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess you use the wrong `addView` method. Try the one from ViewPager -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addView%28android.view.View%2C%20int%2C%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29

Comment: @RalphBergmann just tried it: val viewPager = container as ViewPager
            viewPager.addView(rootLayout, 0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)) - Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Could you omit that line where you're setting layout params and use `container.addView(rootLayout, 0)` instead

Comment: @KingsleyAdio sure, just tried it -> val viewPager = container as ViewPager
            viewPager.addView(rootLayout, 0)  - Made no difference.

Comment: @WolfBane Found your bug. See my answer below

Comment: You're not setting LayoutParams for some of the views, including the ViewPager which should be MATCH_PARENT for both width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your full activity code. It appears you are setting a `CoordinatorLayout` layout params on your view pager, but you are forgetting to set the behavior, seeing that you also have an `AppBarLayout` in the hierarchy. Hence, the view pager content is being drawn behind the tab layout. You can verify this by using the layout inspector in AS.

Doing the following should fix your issue

```
val pagerParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
pagerParams.behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
viewPager.layoutParams = pagerParams
```

You could also take advantage of Kotlin's `apply` function

```
viewPager.layoutParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT).apply {
    behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You are a star!  This solved the problem.  Once i changed the code to set the view pager layout params, and tweaked the positioning a bit, it works like a charm.

Comment: Glad it helped :)